# How can I require customers to fill out a custom field when purchasing certain products?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm using the Commerce framework. I use the commerce_license and commerce_recurring modules to sell subscription memberships to users.

I'm trying to implement gift memberships, so that User A (the "purchaser") can pay for a subscription for User B (the "recipient").

So, when the purchaser checks out, I need to prompt them for the recipient's email address. How can I do this?

(I can imagine other scenarios where you might want to prompt the customer for a "gift message", or a line of custom text to print on a personalized mug, or something like that.)

I know that the Commerce framework has [product attributes](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/product-architecture/product-attributes), which allow customers to specify things such as color, size, etc. However, as far as I can tell, this doesn't support free-text fields – only radio buttons, select boxes, and the like.

Any ideas?

Bonus question: I'll need to validate the recipient's email address before allowing the purchase, so I can make sure they don't already *have* a subscription. Any thoughts on how to approach that?

Thanks!

Comment: `I'll need to validate the recipient's email address before allowing the purchase` use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) where the email address appears and add a custom validation function to the `#validation` array so that it performs this check.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "Recipient email" field to your order item type and expose it to the Add to Cart form. It's up to you then to override the normal fulfillment process that creates entities for the current user, directing them to another user account instead. You'll also need to accommodate the edge case of a customer buying on behalf of a person who doesn't have a user account yet.

cf. https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/order-items